# How to make the TextBox placed properly under the search entry in Tkinter?

Tags: python, tkinter

```
def initUI(self):
     self.columnconfigure(5, weight=1)
     self.rowconfigure(3, weight=1)
     self.search_label = Label(self, text='Keyword:')
     self.search_label.grid(row=0, column=0, padx=5)

     self.keywords = StringVar()
     self.search_bar = Entry(self, width=30,textvariable=self.keywords)
     self.search_bar.grid(row=0, column=1)

     self.search_button = Button(self, text="Search",
                          command=self.handler_search)
     self.search_button.grid(row=0, column=3, padx=5)
     self.pack(fill=BOTH)#, expand='yes')
     #self.pack(fill=BOTH)
     self.box = Text(self, state='disabled')
     self.box.grid(row=1, column=0)
```

The UI is made up of three sub frames, the text editor is one, the side buttons are formed inside another one, and the search is inside another one. The snippet above is the UI for search.

See screenshot: https://i.stack.imgur.com/TOxvT.png

I want to place a text box to be part of the search frame, which is under the search entry. I want it to extend the bottom area as much as possible.

I've tried to expand, fill, etc, but it doesn't solve the problem that entry gets stretched, and my textbox is cut off (I've added scrollbar previously but it was cut off as well).

Where is the problem? Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Get yourself a piece of graph paper and draw out your GUI. The problem should become evident.

You are putting the entry widget in column 1, the text widget in column 0. I'm not entirely sure of the effect you are looking for, but you can either move the text widget to column 1, or leave it in column 0 and have it span a couple of columns.

Assuming you want the text widget to be the whole width of the label-entry-button combination, and you want the label widget to be only as big as it needs to be, I would stop using grid and start using pack for this part of the GUI by doing the following:

1. create a frame for the area as a whole; you can set it's borderwidth to zero if you want it to be invisible
2. create an inner frame for the entry widget, label and search button. pack it to the top, fill=x
3. create the text widget, pack it to the bottom, fill=both, expand=True
4. create the label, pack it on the left of the inner frame
5. create the search button, pack it on the right of the inner frame
6. create the entry widget, pack it on the left of the inner frame, fill=x, expand=True

That will give you a self-contained megawidget with proper resize behavior that you can place wherever you want in the main application.

Build your GUI in sections, and make liberal use of inner frames to achieve the look and behavior you are striving for, and use a geometry manager that is right for each section. If you need something aligned in a grid, use grid. If you don't need a true grid but you do have independent rows or columns, use pack. pack excels at placing things in rows or columns. Grid excels at lining things up in a grid.  Pick the right tool for the job.

Comment: Thanks Bryan. In the meantime, why is putting in column 1 wrong? The row is different though.

Comment: @cpplearner: maybe I misunderstood what you want, but it appears you want an entry on top of a text widget. For that to happen they need to occupy the same column. If the text is only in column zero, and the entry is in column one, they can't line up.